# Bound on "width" of points in a plane

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose we define width $w(P)$ of point set $P$ in a plane to be the ratio of the maximum distance to the minimum distance between the points in $P$.

(Assume unique coordinates so that $w(p)$ is finite.)

Can we lower bound $w(p)$ by some function $f(n)$ where $n = |~P~|$?

Comment: Your $f(n) = 1 / r(n)$ where the best $r^2$ values known for $n = 2\, ...\, 30$ are listed at [Minimizing the Ratio of Maximum to Minimum Distance](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/maxmin/).